# kth largest element(string) in an array based on length

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to find the kth largest element in an array(of strings) and return them according to the rank.

Example -

Input

```
var array = ['java','python','javascript','C','Swift','Dart'];
```

Expected Output

```
[['javascript', 1],
 ['python', 2],
 ['Swift', 3],
 ['java', 4],
 ['Dart', 4],
 ['C', 5]]
```

I tried this -

```js
var rank = 0
var result = []
var arr = ['java','python','javascript','C','Swift','Dart'];
arr.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length);
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i+1]===undefined){
            break;
        }
        else if (arr[i].length>arr[i+1].length){
        ++rank} 
       result.push([arr[i],rank])
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

But as you can see, it dint work. How do I approach this? A little help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = ['java','python','javascript','C','Swift','Dart'];
arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
const res = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {acc.push([el, acc.length == 0 ? 1 : el.length == acc[acc.length-1][0].length ? acc[acc.length-1][1] : acc[acc.length-1][1]+1]); return acc}, [])
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

If you want to do it your way, you can do something like the following:

```js
let rank = 1
const arr = ['java','python','javascript','C','Swift','Dart'];
arr.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length);
const result = [[arr[0], 1]]
for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        if (arr[i].length<arr[i-1].length){
        ++rank} 
       result.push([arr[i],rank])
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: Your second solution ("my way") does not work. This is the output to that - ```[["javascript",1],["python",1],["Swift",1],["java",1],["Dart",1],["C",1]]```
Although I was looking for a solution "my way" with conventional for loops without reduce etc

Comment: this is the old version you are testing. I made an edit subsequently. Please check again. @RajarshiGhoshal

Comment: oh wow! nice! works! but I don't get it, your latest code looks the same as your previous version. Would you be kind enough to explain?

Comment: It's this line: `if (arr[i].length<arr[i-1].length){`. In the previous version it was `if (arr[i].length>arr[i-1].length){`.

Comment: Ah ok! my bad! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the fact that object properties are iterated in order of index value:

```js
const array = ['java','python','javascript','C','Swift','Dart'];

const buckets = Object.fromEntries(array.map(a => [a.length, []]));
for (let word of array) buckets[word.length].push(word);
const result = Object.values(buckets)
                     .reverse()
                     .map((bucket, rank) => bucket.map(word => [rank+1, word]))
                     .flat();

console.log(result);
```